# I try to show ListView with checkbox but method getBox() in not resloved

Tags: java, android

This is my MainActivity file and here i used getBox() method and im getting 'cannot resolve the method' error. How to resolve?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
ListAdapter boxAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fillData();
    boxAdapter = new ListAdapter1(this, products);

    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
    lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);
}

void fillData() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        products.add(new Product("Product " + i, i * 100,
                R.drawable.abc_ic_search, false));
    }
}

public void showResult(View v) {
    String result = "Selected Product are :";
    int totalAmount=0;
    for (Product p : boxAdapter.getBox()) {
        if (p.box){
            result += "\n" + p.name;
            totalAmount+=p.price;
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, result+"\n"+"Total Amount:="+totalAmount, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

And this is my ListAdapter1 java file-Here i have defined the method fox getBox()

Here i have defined the methode= for getBox:

```
ArrayList<Product> getBox() {
    ArrayList<Product> box = new ArrayList<Product>();
    for (Product p : objects) {
        if (p.box)
            box.add(p);
    }
    return box;
   }
```

Please clear this error and explain me why im getting such a error in my code.

Comment: Also make sure the method is public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `ListAdapter boxAdapter;` line with `ListAdapter1 boxAdapter;`